# How to allow aws s3 bucket contents only to publicly serve a certain domain?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I am using aws s3 to store my website pictures and video contents. File links from s3 are directly output to html/php.

The problem is that some other sites linked my picture/video, which heavily increased s3 traffic usage, and off course increased the pay bill.

I know in some case people use referer header to prohibit external sites linking. But in this case, picture/video go out directly from s3, not my domain.

Can some one help to achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499049/preventing-amazon-s3-bandwidth-stealing

Comment: thanks so much. that's just what i want. i did search but not get this one.

Answer (score 6):

You can use Amazon bucket policy like :

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "http referer policy example",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Allow get requests originated from www.example.com and example.com",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:Referer": [
                        "http://www.example.com/*",
                        "http://example.com/*"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

which is explained in detail at : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html

Comment: please could you add more detail, refining it to answer the **exact question.** Cheers